# Invalid binary in itunes connect

Tags: email, binary, app-store-connect

When i upload app to the itunes connect, i see invalid binary and email:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "appname". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Your application bundle's
>   signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported.
>   Please check your Xcode project's code signing entitlements
>   configuration, and remove any unneeded entitlements.
>
> Specifically, key "com.apple.developer.pass-type-identifiers" is not
>   supported.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
>   and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission
>   process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then
>   deliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

What can i do to normalize it?

Answer (score 2):

Passes are not available until iOS 6.  Here is what you should do:

1. Go to the iOS provisioning portal.
2. On the left click App IDs.
3. Click Configure "appname" and uncheck the 'Enable Passes' check mark.
4. On the left click Provisioning, then the Distribution tab.
5. Click 'edit' for the distribution profile associated with "appname", then reselect your app and save.
6. Delete the old distribution profile in XCode and download this new one in its place.

Submitting apps has changed man...it's changed...