# invalid binary, email received

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload an app to app store, and I'm getting a lot of trouble.

Now I received this email:

```
Dear developer,
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "usualBike". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected: 
Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported. Please check your Xcode project's code signing entitlements configuration, and remove any unneeded entitlements. 
Specifically, key "com.apple.developer.default-data-protection" is not supported. 
Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported. Please check your Xcode project's code signing entitlements configuration, and remove any unneeded entitlements. 
Specifically, key "com.apple.developer.pass-type-identifiers" is not supported. 
Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary. 
Regards,
The App Store team
```

The second one I found this:

[Invalid binary in itunes connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431929/invalid-binary-in-itunes-connect)

But i have iOS 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably means that you have Data Protection and Passes enabled for your App ID in the iOS provisioning portal. This is not supported for iOS 5.1

You should disable this by:

- Going to the iOS provisioning portal
- Open the App ID tab
- Click configure next to the App ID you're currently using
- Unselect the Enable for Passes and Enable for Data Protection options
- Redownload the provision for your application and rebuild it using this new provision.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the second issue, the com.apple.pass-type-identifiers, but the other one continue unsolved

Comment: It could be that the 'com.apple.developer.default-data-protection' key is still present in the Entitlements.plist file. If it's not, check if the Enable for Data Protection was correctly disabled in the provision.