# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Data Protection key not supported

Tags: iphone, encryption, app-store, app-store-connect, data-protection

I have received an mail from Apple that my app has been rejected.

The reason is:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Secure Send". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Your application bundle's
>   signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported.
>   Please check your Xcode project's code signing entitlements
>   configuration, and remove any unneeded entitlements.
>
> **Specifically, key "com.apple.developer.default-data-protection" is not
>   supported.**
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
>   and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission
>   process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then
>   deliver the corrected binary.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719035/invalid-binary-email-received) where the exactly same issue appears. The marked solution is to disable data protection in the provisioning profile. But when I do this my app cannot store the files securely using data protection, what it definitely should do!

I have also tried to disable Data Protection but then all files are stored in `DataProtectionClassNone` regardless which protection class is set.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this for iOS 5 and above?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, did you get this sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it is **definitely not deprecated**! It will be introduced with iOS6 and I had these settings because of my iOS6 Beta. That's the reason why our binary was invalid.

Our deployment target was set to iOS5 but this configuration key will be introduced with iOS6. So the automatic binary check failed because it didn't know this flag for iOS5 apps.

More on this:

1. https://devforums.apple.com/message/687733
2. https://devforums.apple.com/message/702754

Answer (score -1):

It's deprecated in iOS 5 and I believe it's supposed to go away entirely in iOS 6. You have to use use system encryption calls instead of using transparent encryption; there's a great project out there called [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) that packages it all up for you.

You also need a [SNAP-R](https://snapr.bis.doc.gov/snapr/exp/UserLoginLoad) from the government to legally use encryption in iOS. Apple will ask for your ERN when you submit it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are using system encryption and everything works fine except the rejection. I have disabled this flag and uploaded it again. Everything was fine... I began with iOS5 so I didn't know that it is deprecated. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: Well, I digged into this and it is definitely NOT deprecated. It has been introduced with the iOS6 Beta !!!